# Problems with authentication and read/write to "MIFARE Plus S" cards using WinSCard library and ACR1283L device in C++

Tags: c++, authentication, mifare, winscard

I am using an **ACS ACR1283L** device to read/write to **MIFARE PLUS S** cards.
I can successfully connect and get the card UID

**Code to connect**

```
void multithread:: CardConnect(QString s)
{
    LONG  lReturn;
    DWORD dwAP;

    lReturn = SCardConnect(hSC,
                            reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR>(s.unicode()),
                            SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
                            SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1,
                            &hCardHandle,
                            &dwAP);

    if(SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed SCardConnect\n";
    }
    else
    {
        return Status = true;
        // Use the connection.
        // Display the active protocol.
        switch (dwAP)
        {
            case SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0:
                std::cout << "Active protocol T0\n";
                break;
            case SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1:
                std::cout << "Active protocol T1\n";
                break;
            case SCARD_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED:
                std::cout << "Active protocol is undefined\n";
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Active protocol unnegotiated or unknown\n";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Code to get the card uid**

```
void multithread::CardTransmit()
{
   BYTE  pbRecv[258];
   BYTE  pbSend[] = {0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
   DWORD dwSend,dwRecv;
   dwSend = sizeof(pbSend);
   dwRecv = sizeof(pbRecv);

   LONG lReturn = SCardTransmit(hCardHandle,
                            SCARD_PCI_T1,
                            pbSend,
                            dwSend,
                            nullptr,
                            pbRecv,
                            &dwRecv);
   if(SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn)
   {
       qDebug() << "Failed SCardTransmit";
   }
   else
   {
       QByteArray qdb = QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pbRecv));
       qdb.chop(1);
       cardUID = QString(qdb.toHex());
       qDebug() << "Card uid: "<< cardUID;
   }
}
```

At this point I authenticate the card.
**Code to authenticate**

```
bool multithread::CardAuthenticate(int blockNo)
{
    // Authenticate the card
    BYTE authCmd[] = {0x60, 0xC2, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    BYTE key[6] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66}; // Replace with actual key
    BYTE response[256];
    DWORD responseLen = sizeof(response);
    LONG lReturn = SCardTransmit(hCardHandle, SCARD_PCI_T1, authCmd, sizeof(authCmd), NULL, response, &responseLen);

    if(SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed SCardTransmit\n";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Success Authentication";
        return true;
    }
}
```

I get "Success Authentication" but after that I am not able to write any data to the card and I don't understand why.
I read in internet that if I switch from SLO to SL1 then I can treat the card as if it were a MIFARE classic instead of MIFARE PLUS S. Unfortunately my experience on this is too poor and I am unable to do. I would have some help in switch from SL0 to SL1 and write a basic data